# Welchem Zweck dient "eines" plus Nomen? "Eines Laplace"?

Tags: word-choice

> Weit, weit entfernt von der mechanischen Welt **eines Newton oder eines
>   Laplace**, in der winzige starre Bausteine in einem unveränderlichen
>   geometrischen Raum bis in alle Ewigkeit präzise ihre Bahn zogen.

Kann jeder Name oder nur berühmte mit *eines* benutzt werden? Warum nimmt man nicht *von*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can say

> Weit, weit entfernt von der mechanischen Welt von Newton oder Laplace

There is a subtle difference to

> Weit, weit entfernt von der mechanischen Welt eines Newton oder eines Laplace

Both constructions share that they express possession. In the first example, it is the world of Newton or Laplace. This is definite.
In the second example, this becomes more indefinite. It is the world of "a Newton" or "a Laplace", to just refer to two famous physicists who gave tremendous contributions to classical physics. However, because the indefinite pronoun is used (in the genitive case, to express possession), similiar people are also included. You could rephrase it like

> Weit, weit entfernt von der mechanischen Welt von Leuten wie Newton oder Laplace

This, of course, works with any name, as grammar doesn't know anything about the fame of people. However,  if I were to write

> Weit, weit entfernt von der mechanischen Welt eines user53

this is - again - grammatically fine, but if it still makes sense to write it in a book about presumably quantum physics ... well, you have to ask yourself about that.