# Keine Beugung in „eines Newton“. Warum ohne s-Endung?

Tags: genitive

Nächste Frage wurde neulich gestellt:

[Welchem Zweck dient "eines" plus Nomen? "Eines Laplace"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54625/welchem-zweck-dient-eines-plus-nomen-eines-laplace)

Da lautet es

> Weit, weit entfernt von der mechanischen Welt *eines Newton* oder eines Laplace, ...

Es gab keinen Einwand gegen den Mangel der Genitivendung *s*. Ich hätte „eines Newtons“ erwartet.

Warum ist es richtig ohne *s*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erklärungsvorschlag: Es kann nicht "eines Newtons" lauten, weil es sich nicht um den Genitiv von "ein Newton" (siehe [die gleichnamige Maßeinheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_(Einheit))) handelt, sondern auf die spezifische Person Isaac Newtons Bezug genommen wird. Familiennamen (männlicher Personen) stehen im Genitiv regelmäßig ohne Artikel:

> Die Kanzlerschaft Kohls...

statt

> Die Kanzlerschaft des Kohls (oder: eines Kohls)...

Steht der Name ausnahmsweise mit Artikel (bestimmt oder unbestimmt), wird er nicht dekliniert.

> Die Memoiren des Kanzlers Kohl...

Klassische Ausnahme:

> "Die Leiden des jungen Werthers"

Vielleicht kann man die Konstruktion auch als Ellipse verstehen: "eines (Forschers/Wissenschaftlers wie) Newton". Das deklinierte Element wäre also aus stilistischen Gründen entfallen; der Name stünde in einer solchen Fügung generell im Nominativ und bleibt es auch, wenn das deklinierte Element entfallen ist.